# SQLClient String Function NVARCHAR instead of STR

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlclient

I'm am trying to use SQLClient for Entity Framework functions, but I'm having some issues. I need to convert `ID` (which in the database is a an `int`) to a `nvarchar` so that I can compare it using wildcards.

This works to an extent (i.e. it builds and executes without erroring), however it's not what I need to do as db side, it returns the wrong results. In fact, it returns 0 rows, when it should be returning a number.

```
return "SqlServer.STR(ID) LIKE '824%'";
```

The above line basically translates to the below line in SQL

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE STR(ID) LIKE '824%'
```

What I need in SQL is the following line (or something similar) because this returns the correct number of rows.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), ID) LIKE '824%'
```

I've tried using:

```
return "CAST(ID AS NVARCHAR(50)) LIKE '824%'";
```

But this gives the following error at runtime:

> Type 'NVARCHAR' could not be found. Make sure that the required
>   schemas are loaded and that the namespaces are imported correctly.

Can anyone tell me how to do this using SqlClient string functions, or some other variant?

Thanks all.

Comment: Could you change your like to '% 824%' ?

Comment: Yes, this does appear to work, many thanks. Can I ask why exactly it works like that? Thanks again. If you add this to the answers, I will mark it as answered.

Comment: Maybe you should store the data in a way that makes complex calculations on it unnecessary. If you insist, I have provided an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using the SqlFunction.StringConvert() function. There is no overload for int, so you have to type cast

```
var test = dataContext.Table1
                      .Where(f => SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double) f.Id)
                                               .Trim()
                                               .StartsWith("824"))
                      .Select(f => SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double) f.Id)
                                               .Trim())
                      .ToList();
```

This will be converted as

```
SELECT 
LTRIM(RTRIM(STR( CAST( [Extent1].[Id] AS float)))) AS [C1]
FROM [dbo].[Table1] AS [Extent1]
WHERE (LTRIM(RTRIM(STR( CAST( [Extent1].[Id] AS float)))) LIKE N'4%')
```

Comment: I consider this to be a hack. The problem is the right-aligning, not that the search condition is wrong. I don't like to plaster fixed over bugs, I fix the root cause. Get rid of the right-aligning (which is crazy behavior).

Comment: But using `SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)x.Id))` will not solve it because EntityFramwork is using STR to convert it.

Comment: I fail to find any way clean to convert an int into a string with EF. This is very disappointing.

Comment: actually .Trim() works. Thanks for your comment about it being a hack It forced me to dung further. I'll update my anwsers.

Comment: I'm forced to upvote this disgusting hack. I'd probably investigate custom EF functions. There seems to be a way to reference T-SQL functionality and casts.

Comment: Thank you both for you comments, this is just what I need.